# Not able to view measurement after creating continuous query

Tags: influxdb

I have a measurement that has the following fields in InfluxDB. The measurement name is data.

```
Measurement name: data
Time                    Device          Interface    Metric    Value
2016-10-11T19:00:00Z    device1_name    int_name    In_bits    10
2016-10-11T19:00:00Z    device2_name    int_name    Out_bits    5
.
.
.
```

I have created a continuous query as follows:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "test_query" ON "db_name" BEGIN SELECT sum("value") as Sumin INTO "data.copy" FROM "data" where metric = 'In_bits' GROUP BY time(15m), device END
```

After creating this, how do I see the results saved in new measurement data.copy? After creating this query, I am not able to find the new measurement that has been created. If I'm doing something wrong, I would like to get more input on this matter. Thanks!

Comment: I've only ever used `GROUP BY` with `time()` on CQs. That's also all that's shown in the documentation. Could you try removing the `device` term from the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I made a small change to the continuous query. Instead of saving it in 'data.copy' , I modified it to save it into datacopy. This works for now. Thanks.

Comment: Ah cool. I see it now. :) Thanks for sharing!

Comment: CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "cqone" ON "NOAA_water_database" BEGIN SELECT mean("water_level") as mean INTO "meanfeet" FROM "h2o_feet" GROUP BY time(5m) END 

this is my cq for the test db.. please let me know if there any mistake found